# A lemma for generic freeness

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

say a B-algebra A satisfies (†) if for each finitely generated A-module M, there exists a nonzero f ∈ B such that $M_f$ is a free $B_f$-module.

Grothendieck's generic Freeness lemma States that if B is a Noetherian domain and A is a finitely generated B algebra, then A satisfies (†).

Its an exercise (7.4.G) in Ravi Vakil's  algebraic geometry notes to reduce this statement to following claim: if A is a finitely-generated B-algebra satisfying (†), then A[T] does too.   that is the exercise is to assume this claim to be true and prove the generic freeness lemma. ** My question is how to do this?**

In The exercise preceeding this one I proved that B itself satisfies (†).  Thus if I could prove (†) is Preserved under  passing to a quotient  I could just Adjoin the generators to B as indeterminates (using the claim inductively) and then take a quotient to get A.  but I don't know how to prove that (†)  is preserved by passing to a quotient.

Comment: I think this is a purely formal thing, no? Say $A = B[T_{1}, \ldots, T_{n}]/I$. The data of an $A$-module is the same thing is a $B[T_{1}, \ldots, T_{n}]$-module $M$ such that $IM = 0$. (If you prefer, put another way, if you think of an $A$-module structure on an abelian group $M$ as being given by a ring morphism $A \to End(M)$, then $M$ inherits a natural $B[T_{1}, \ldots, T_{n}]$-module structure by composing $A \to End(M)$ with the quotient morphism $B[T_{1}, \ldots, T_{n}] \to A$.) Note that the associated $B[T_{1}, \ldots, T_{n}]$-module structure is compatible with the $B$-algebra...

Comment: ...structure $B \to A$. Hence, if you're handed an $A$-module $M$, then you can regard $M$ as a $B[T_{1}, \ldots, T_{n}]$-module in a natural way which respects the $B$-action on $M$. Applying the version of generic freeness for free $B$-algebras, you can produce the desired $f$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim  oh yes of course .   The mistake I made was in worrying that f might be in I ( I was thinking of B,A as a ring extension) But of course technically f is in B and so it's still not zero when you pass to the quotient.  Thank you!

Comment: It's possible that the image of $f$ in $A$ is $0$ (or, more generally, that $f$ acts by $0$ on $M$). In this case, $M_{f} = 0$, and so is trivially a free $B_{f}$-module. (For example, let $k$ be a field, and let $B = k[X]$, and let $A$ be a $B$-algebra via the morphism of $k$-algebras $k[X] \to k$ which sends $X$ to $0$. Taking $M = k$, you can take $f = X$.)

Comment: You may also look up the proof given at https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/051R

Comment: As pointed out by Alex, it seems that using restriction of scalars (by the map $B[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]\to B[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]/I$) might not be enough to prove this.